# Did select row at index path not working on second time on select row in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In a table view, did select row at index path not second time when select row. Here is my code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!self.thirdvc) {
        self.thirdvc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdview"];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdvc animated:YES]; // this is right way .
}
```

Comment: what is **self.thirdvc**?

Comment: this method not getting called second time?

Comment: Self.thirdvc is third view controller.

Comment: add the break point and check once

Comment: is didSelectRowAtIndexPath called second time ?

Comment: Thanks brothers problem is solved now

Comment: what was the issue @AbhishekPathak ?

Comment: @KKRocks the issue is did select row at index path was working only first time when select row . But this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your tableview is allow only `single selection`. From your storyboard select your `tableview`, from `attribute inspector` select `single selection` for option `selection`. or you can set it by code like,

```
 yourTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because after you select the first time, it is marked as selected, so the second time you press, it will become unselected. so just deselect the row:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (!self.thirdvc) { 
        self.thirdvc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdview"];
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Ok sir I try this.

Comment: sir still not work on second time when select another row

Comment: try replace the last line with this: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.thirdvc animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `thirdvc` as the instance variable of the class and in `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` method, you are check if it's nil, then instantiate it and push it to `thirdvc`. So in second time thirdvc is not nil, so it's not working. To make it work change your code as:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

    if (!self.thirdvc) {
    self.thirdvc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdview"];
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdvc animated:YES];
    }
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdvc animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: bring `[self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdvc animated:YES];`  outside of the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Replace code with this one:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.thirdvc = nil;
    if (!self.thirdvc) {
        self.thirdvc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdview"];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdvc animated:YES]; // this is right way .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cell taped");
    NSDictionary *temDict1 =[objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```